# Python PyAudio mimic ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pyaudio

I have an audio utility in Ubuntu that processes audio data in a streaming fashion, let's call it `/bin/speech_to_text_transcription`.

I am able to pipe to it, streaming WAV data from microphone as follows:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel error \
-f pulse -i default \
-acodec pcm_s16le \
-ar 16000 -ac 1 -ab 256k \
-f wav - \
| /bin/speech_to_text_transcription
```

As you can see, I am feeding a mono-channel WAV audio file sampled at 16kHz to `/bin/audio_process`. I know the above works because I see successful output process

I wanted to mimic a similar setup using Python `PyAduio` such that I could run the same setup as above as follows:

`python stream_audio.py | /bin/speech_to_text_transcription`

I need to do this because my target host does not have FFmpeg installed.

```
import pyaudio
import pickle, sys

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 1
fs = 16000  # Record at 16000 samples per second
seconds = 1000

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio
stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    pickle.dump(data, sys.stdout.buffer)
```

However, I am unable to mimic the setup. What could be missing?

Thanks